# How do I use a select element's onchange event to pass an object instead of a string in AngularDart?

Tags: angular-dart

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
<select (ngModelChange)="addChild($event)">
    <option>Add</option>
    <option [value]="null">New Item</option>
    <option *ngFor="let child of menuItem.children" [value]="child">
        {{child.title}}
    </option>
</select>
```

While it compiles, the addChild method is not called. VSCode is reporting that "The bound output ngModelChange does not exist on any directive or on the element" - so what directive do I need to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularDart's SelectElement only supports Strings for values. If you want to pass arbitrary objects, you will need to use a different component - one that supports such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your first line to:

```
<select (change)="addChild($event)">
```

That should do the job.

You may also find convenient to print strings instead of full objects where it is expected:

```
<option *ngFor="let child of menuItem.children" [value]="child.id">
```

and maybe (or maybe not):

```
<select (ngModelChange)="addChild(child.id)">
```

if it works better for you and you have a suitable property, of course. YMMV.

Comment: The $event is complaining with: The argument type 'Event' cannot be assigned to the parameter type 'MenuItem'. 
[value] is also complaining with: Attribute value expression (of type MenuItem) is not assignable to component input (of type String). 

While it compiles, it explodes on render. I was under the impression that the ngModel (something like ngValue and ngModelChange) could overcome this limitation?

Comment: I have suspects about the addChild method and its signature. I would then simply do a print() of the parameters, inside the body of the addChild method. Once you're comfortable with the parameters' types and structure, then you can start elaborate on that. That's my suggestion.